How to read JSON array of arrays with mixed values in Retrofit 2?
I'm trying to read the following data from the API:
[
    [
        1724180400000,
        "59191.45000000",
        "59597.28000000",
        "59137.78000000",
        "59511.99000000",
        "544.56764000",
        1724183999999,
        "32351755.73378980",
        51002,
        "290.20494000",
        "17241827.16012430",
        "0"
    ],
    [
        1724184000000,
        "59512.00000000",
        "59722.72000000",
        "59421.38000000",
        "59589.07000000",
        "301.58055000",
        1724187599999,
        "17968010.37382020",
        23563,
        "169.48375000",
        "10099057.30721750",
        "0"
    ]
]

But Retrofit expects a JSON response starting with '{' instead of '['.
I tried serializing the data with the following dependencies:
implementation(libs.retrofit)
implementation(libs.retrofit2.kotlinx.serialization.converter)
implementation(libs.okhttp)
implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)

When I tell Retrofit to expect a list with lists it states that 'Serializer for class 'Any' is not found'. How to serialize this response type with only arrays containing mixed types (String and Int)?

"But Retrofit expects a JSON response starting with '{' instead of '['." -- Retrofit does not expect anything. You told Retrofit what to expect, and so there is a problem in what you have in your Retrofit API (e.g., the @GET-annotated function). I recommend that you edit your question and provide that function, along with the class declaration of what that function is returning, so we can compare and contrast it with the JSON that you are expecting.

I'm just asking how to tell Retrofit to expect this type of response. Obviously everything I tried so far was wrong. I Was hoping to read the data in my service as List<List>.

"I'm just asking how to tell Retrofit to expect this type of response" -- the issue is less of Retrofit and more of Kotlin Serialization, which is the converter that you are using. Retrofit is not involved, other than by delegating converting the JSON to types to Kotlin Serialization. So, you need to determine how Kotlin Serialization handles lists of disparate types. I have not had to worry about this (that JSON structure is not the best...), but I would explore this option.

If type does not matter, you can just use type String.
@GET("test")
fun test(): Call<List<List<String>>>

If type matters, you can use JsonPrimitive.
@GET("test")
fun test(): Call<List<List<JsonPrimitive>>>

After you received data, you can parse it as List<List<Any>> like this.
val result: List<List<JsonPrimitive>> = response.body()!!

val parsedResult: List<List<Any>> = result.map { innerItem ->
    innerItem.map {
         if (it.isNumber) it.asInt
         else it.asString
    }
}

println(parsedResult)


This answer is great! I wasted hours while I just had to type the inner list as JsonPrimitive. Because the network calls are inside a suspend function, the Call type is not needed in my scenario. But can you explain to me what JsonPrimitive actually is and when do I use it? Is it only to replace Any to get at least an exhaustive set of possible types?

@Marc JSON has 6 data types. Among these, String, Number (including Int, Long, Double, etc.), and Boolean are considered JSON primitives. So, you can use JsonPrimitive if your API response contains mixed primitive data types. But, if you own the API, it is generally recommended to avoid using JsonPrimitive since API should maintain consistent data types (not mixed).

It's not my API. I think the data is formatted this way because they serve large amounts of data and want to keep the network data size as small as possible. But as a consumer I don't find it convenient at all... Anyway, your answer was very helpful in solving the issue! I will use JsonPrimitive in my Android apps to handle these kind of responses.

The answers in this thread helped a lot to understand and solve the problem. In my Android app I implemented the solution like this:
In the api service (Retrofit 2 interface)
@GET("klines.json")
suspend fun getKlines(): List<List<JsonPrimitive>>

In the network repository, fetch and convert the rawJson to my custom Kline class
override suspend fun getKlines(): List<Kline> {
    val rawJson = apiService.getKlines()
    return rawJson.map { data ->
        Kline(
            timestamp = data[0].long,
            open = data[1].double,
            high = data[2].double,
            low = data[3].double,
            close = data[4].double,
            volume = data[5].double,
            closeTime = data[6].long,
            quoteAssetVolume = data[7].double,
            numberOfTrades = data[8].int,
            takerBuyBaseAssetVolume = data[9].double,
            takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume = data[10].double
        )
    }
}

The Call type was not needed in my scenario because the functions are called from within a coroutine scope.
The rawJson result in logcat:
[[1724151600000, "60716.01000000", "60734.91000000", "60401.90000000", "60518.82000000", "1086.55870000", 1724155199999, "65807817.60717790", 58639, "538.35193000", "32602791.90598670", "0"], [...] ] 

This implementation works for me, but better solutions are appreciated!
